# ASP.NET Core - Auth error after deploy - IDX10503: Signature validation failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, aspnetboilerplate

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core 1.1 MVC web site, with OpenID authentication to Azure AD.
Authentication works fine locally on my dev machine. However, when I deploy it to the server, it throws an error after logging into the microsoft login redirect.
I'be been researching online for about 2 days, and have found similar issues, but nothing exactly like this. 
My local dev box is windows 10, visual studio 2017.
The server I am deploying to is Server 2008R2, with the .net core server hosting runtime installed.

Here are the errors:
ERROR 2017-07-27 10:38:05,667 [4    ] on.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMiddleware - Exception occurred while processing message.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. 
ERROR 2017-07-27 10:38:05,680 [4    ] e.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware - An unhandled exception has occurred: Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x000D
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x000D
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameHeaders.ThrowInvalidHeaderCharacter(Char ch)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameHeaders.ValidateHeaderCharacters(String headerCharacters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameHeaders.ValidateHeaderCharacters(StringValues headerValues)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameResponseHeaders.SetValueFast(String key, StringValues value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameHeaders.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.set_Item(String key, StringValues value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpResponse.Redirect(String location, Boolean permanent)
   at FastInfo.Web.Startup.Startup.OnAuthenticationFailed(FailureContext context) in C:\SourceCode\Fast\FastInfo\src\FastInfo.Web\Startup\Startup.cs:line 168
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRemoteCallbackAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

---

I am possibly missing some module or extension for OpenID tokens to work on IIS 7.5?

token header:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q",
  "kid": "VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q"
}

payload (edited):
{
  "aud": "b0337ae2-2097-4dd3-be43-983fee4217bd",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{i removed guid}/",
  "iat": 1501263956,
  "nbf": 1501263956,
  "exp": 1501267856,
  "aio": "Y2ZgYDD9/5YpiT9XXmCDXMn/EzzPGa3nMbxfudOgpnfDsZk7/QMA",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "c_hash": "02fpZ5B7FecFoRVdeJi6Qw",
  "family_name": "mylastname",
  "given_name": "Joe",
  "ipaddr": "##.###.###.##",
  "name": "Joe mylastname",
  "nonce": "636368610551942171.ZTU5ZGZmZmQtZDgzNS00MTEyLWExZjAtNWI3MTA2NGJlN2RkYzY0OTdkZjctZTZkMy00OTk2LWIxNjgtZTlhMDkxNmY0MzFh",
  "oid": "26945208-7b3f-45ed-9b40-f33b9d767071",
  "platf": "3",
  "roles": [
    "Admin"
  ],
  "sub": "y-sRfJAMdidDOedJeyr7kLhH8BCfkV_YCdyT1p2mOmk",
  "tid": "{i removed guid}",
  "unique_name": "jwashek@fastsolutions.com",
  "upn": "jwashek@fastsolutions.com",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Thanks for any help,
Joe

Comment: After more digging it looks like the Invalid non-ASCII error is not the cause of my auth issue.   The ASCII error is thrown AFTER the token problem, when trying to direct to my error page.   Long story short, I'm thinking the real, main issue is this:

IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey , KeyId: VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q
'.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any indication of why this is failing.

Comment: Would you minding show the claims in the token(both header and payload)? You can decode the token from [this site](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: On the JWT debug site you mentioned, what value do I put in the VERIFY SIGNATURE section.

Comment: Based on the code, the token should be able to verified. I only see this issue when there is `nonce` claim in the header. To verify the signature from that site, you can compose the value with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----{x5c}-----END CERTIFICATE----- `. About value of `x5c`, you can refer the value from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys` by matching `kid`. Is the issue fixed?

Comment: I was able to get it to verify now on the JWT site.   So it seems only the server I am deploying to is having the issue.  It's Server 2008 R2 , IIS 7.5.
Does it have anything to do with the https cert that I have on the server?

Comment: Fei Xue,thank you for your help.  I'm not sure what I did, but it's actually working now.

Comment: Disregard my comment on July 31st, it's not working again.  The token and signature verifies successfully on JWT.io  debug site.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue by sending a single request to the web server with the correct token? I found a similar issue on this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/928) that mentioned the issue may caused by the calling the parallel requests(refer [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/9708)).  If this is the root cause, you need to upgrade the .Net core framework to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since AADB2C will redirect to an HTTPS page, the headers are not well managed and you get this error. Enforce the https on any website using B2C and you may solve this issue

Comment: I don't think I'm connecting with Azure B2C.  I'm connecting with Azure AD, via open ID connect.     I am directing all traffic to https.    The code works fine on my dev machine, both on IIS express and full IIS.   
A few days ago I commented that it did start to work, but for some reason now it's throwing the "IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried" error again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the identity running the application pool.  It didn't have enough rights, from when I've read and am thinking,  not enough rights to access the cert.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error occurs when I want to debug and the visual studio configuration is set to Release